# Use the Euler-Lagrange equation to find the equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus, coupled-oscillators

I have to use the Euler-Lagrange equation

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = 0
$$

to go from

$$
L = T - V = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{m}{2} {\dot{q}_n}^2 - \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{K}{2} {\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)}^2
$$

to

$$
m\ddot{q}_n + \frac{K}{2} \left[ 2 \left(q_n - q_{n-1}\right) - 2 \left(q_{n+1} + - q_n\right) \right] = 0
$$

or

$$
m\ddot{q}_n = K \left( q_{n+1} + q_{n-1} - 2q_n \right)
$$

So I started with

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} = \frac{m}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}} \left( {\dot{q}_n}^2 \right) = \sum_{n=1}^N m\dot{q}_n
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N m\dot{q}_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^N m\ddot{q}_n
$$

Then on the second sum I'm missing something

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = -\frac{K}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial q} {\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)}^2
$$

How does this get anywhere close to the 2nd term in the 3rd equation?

I figured that perhaps I should recalculate for every n, so rewriting the equations:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_n} = \frac{m}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}_n} \left( {\dot{q}_n}^2 \right) = \sum_{n=1}^N m\dot{q}_n
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N m\dot{q}_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^N m\ddot{q}_n
$$
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_n} = -\frac{K}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial q_n} {\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)}^2 =
-\frac{K}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 2{\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)}(-1)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_n} = \frac{K}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 2{\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)}
$$

So for n+1

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{n+1}} = \frac{m}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}_{n+1}} \left( {\dot{q}_n}^2 \right) = 0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{n+1}} = -\frac{K}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial q_{n+1}} {\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)}^2 =
-\frac{K}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 2{\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)}
$$

Now there are 2 (coupled?) equations:

$$
m\ddot{q}_n - \frac{K}{2} 2{\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{K}{2} 2{\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)} = 0
$$

Which result

$$
m\ddot{q}_n + K \left[ {\left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right) - \left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)} \right] = 0
$$

If I can rewrite one of the parentheses n+1 -> n and n -> n-1, then I can get the desired result.

$$
m\ddot{q}_n + K \left[ {\left( q_{n} - q_{n-1} \right) - \left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)} \right] = 0
$$
$$
m\ddot{q}_n + K {\left(- q_{n-1} - q_{n+1} + 2q_n \right)} = 0
$$
$$
m\ddot{q}_n = K {\left(q_{n-1} + q_{n+1} - 2q_n \right)}
$$

But this sounds like BS, so I have no idea what I'm doing. Enlighten me.

Comment: Yes, because you have $N$ particles, you have $N$ coordinates $q_k$, so you have $N$ eom's, one for each $q_k$. With a quick reading, I would say that you derivation is ok.

Comment: Notice that in order to get the eom's for the $n$-th particle, you have to take into account the equation for $q_n$, with a term like $(q_{n+1}-q_n)^2$, but also the equation for $q_{n-1}$, because $q_n$ appears in $(q_n-q_{n-1})^2$.

Comment: So what you're saying is I should do this

(n+1)
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{n+1}} = - K \sum_{n=1}^N \left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)
$$
$$
K \left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right) = 0
$$

(n)
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{n}} = K \sum_{n=1}^N \left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right)
$$
$$
m\ddot{q}_n - K \left( q_{n+1} - q_n \right) = 0
$$

(n-1)
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{n-1}} = K \sum_{n=1}^N \left( q_n - q_{n-1} \right)
$$
$$
- K \left( q_n - q_{n-1} \right) = 0
$$

And the equation of motion is

$$
m\ddot{q}_n - K {\left( + q_n - q_{n-1} \right)} = 0
$$

I'm confused

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. What I wanted to say is that when taking the partial wrt $q_n$ you have two terms that involve $q_n$, these being $(q_{n+1}-q_n)^2+(q_n-q_{n-1})^2$. When you apply the E-L equations taking this into account, the derivation is straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$L= \frac{m}{2}\sum_{n~=~1}^N \dot{q}_n - \frac{K}{2}\sum_{n~=~1}^N(q_{n+1}-q_n)^2$$

Consider the equations of motion for the $k$-th particle:

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_k}-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_k} = 0 $$.

The term of the velocity is easy:

$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_k} = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(m \dot{q}_k)=m\ddot{q}_k$$

With the positions, notice that each coordinate appears in two terms, so

$$ \begin{align}\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_k} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial q_k}\left[-\frac{K}{2}(q_k-q_{k-1})^2-\frac{K}{2}(q_{k+1}-q_k)^2\right]
\\ &= -K(q_k-q_{k-1})+K(q_{k+1}-q_k)=K(q_{k+1}+q_{k-1}-2q_k)\end{align} $$

So, the eom for the $k$-th particle is

$$ m\ddot{q}_k = K(q_{k+1}+q_{k-1}-2q_k) $$

(obviously for $1<k<N$).

**Some comments**

Notice that I have *intentionally* changed the index for the derivation of the eom $k$ with respect to the dummy index $n$ that appears in the summatory. This is a very good practice when working with index notations that can help you to avoid mistakes when performing this calculations.

If you are somehow new to the index notations I recommend you to perform this computations explicitly for some given $N$ (let's say, $N=3$ or $4$), expanding the sums to actually view how it works and convince yourself that the method is right.

Comment: I did expand the sums first, but I've been wrong before and told 'you can't do this here because of that' enough times for a life time since series has been the most difficult subject for me in my graduation. Since I couldn't tell when to use, i.e., a Taylor expansion, I would first expand the sum and if still couldn't get it then I would write it as is.
For this problem in particular I thought "nope, expanding seems too simple".